# M : N relation ship and table

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, cardinality

I have a created a simple db modle for shopping cart lets just consider order , product and shopping cart for now

My question is shopping cart has M:N relation ship with product ? if yes is there a need to create a third table .
I have created third table but it is not making sense for me .I can very well have 
T_SHOPPING_CART table and have id ,product_id,quantity as composite primary key and have values of product stored in it rather then creating another table to store these details. Which one is better approach a third table or composite primary key.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the answer lies in the fundamentals. You already said that `T_SHOPPING_CART` and `T_PRODUCT` have an m:n relationship. So, when you decompose any many to many relationship, it *always* creates an association table (or gerund).

Let us see why your approach will not work. You want to just use a composite id in the T_SHOPPING_CART table

```
T_SHOPPING_CART_ID(ID, Product_Id, quantity)
```

1. If you include quantity in the primary key, every time a user
   changes quantity, your primary key will change. That is not a good
   way to design.
2. What about other attributes you may need? Are you going to add them
   as primary key every time? Eg. You need to design a Discount associated with each shopping cart. How will you store it? Can you have a simple m:1 relationship with a table `Discount`? Since you have a composite key, it will be very inefficient.
   Or if you store the Discount as an attribute in the T_SHOPPING_CART table, it will lead to even severe flaw, redundancy. Data redundancy causes all kinds of anomalies.

T_SHOPPING_CART

```
ID   PRODUCT_ID    QUANTITY         DISCOUNT

1        101           33             2.3

1        102           20             2.3
```

Here, the Discount for shopping cart with id=1 is 2.3. It is redundant i.e. present at 2 places, which causes update, delete, anomalies.

3. If you delete a Product, how will you deal with it? If it is Cascade delete, you will lose all the shopping carts which has that product. If you do not cascade, what will you store in place of the deleted item? Null, default value? Very bad design.

My basic argument is if you read the fundamentals of a many to many relationship, you will find all the answers. Many to many should always be linked with a third table.

Hope it helps.